# Why can't I use State<T> in ViewModel directly with Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from offical sample project [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews).

The `InterestsViewModel` define `uiState` as `StateFlow`, and it is converted as `State<T>` by `collectAsState()` in the Composable function `rememberTabContent`.

I'm very strange why the author doesn't define `uiState` as `State<T>` directly in  `InterestsViewModel`, so I write Code B.

The Code B can be compiled , and it can run, but it display nothing in screen, what is wrong with Code B ?

**Code A**

```
data class InterestsUiState(
    val topics: List<InterestSection> = emptyList(),
    val people: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val publications: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val loading: Boolean = false,
)

class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // UI state exposed to the UI
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    ...
    init {
        refreshAll()
    }

    
    private fun refreshAll() {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }

        viewModelScope.launch {
             ...
            // Wait for all requests to finish
            val topics = topicsDeferred.await().successOr(emptyList())
            val people = peopleDeferred.await().successOr(emptyList())
            val publications = publicationsDeferred.await().successOr(emptyList())

            _uiState.update {
                it.copy(
                    loading = false,
                    topics = topics,
                    people = people,
                    publications = publications
                )
            }
        }
    }
 
}


@Composable
fun rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel): List<TabContent> {
    // UiState of the InterestsScreen
    val uiState by interestsViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    ... 
    return listOf(topicsSection, peopleSection, publicationSection)
}


@Composable
fun InterestsRoute(
    interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel,
    isExpandedScreen: Boolean,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {
    val tabContent = rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel)
    val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }

    InterestsScreen(
        tabContent = tabContent,
        currentSection = currentSection,
        isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
        onTabChange = updateSection,
        openDrawer = openDrawer,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    )
}
```

**Code B**

```
data class InterestsUiState(
    val topics: List<InterestSection> = emptyList(),
    val people: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val publications: List<String> = emptyList(),
    var loading: Boolean = false,
)


class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    
    // UI state exposed to the UI
    private var _uiState by mutableStateOf (InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiState: InterestsUiState = _uiState

    ...
    
    init {
        refreshAll()
    }

    private fun refreshAll() {
        _uiState.loading = true

        viewModelScope.launch {
           ...
            _uiState = _uiState.copy(
                    loading = false,
                    topics = topics,
                    people = people,
                    publications = publications
                )
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel): List<TabContent> {
    // UiState of the InterestsScreen
    val uiState = interestsViewModel.uiState
    ...
    return listOf(topicsSection, peopleSection, publicationSection)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `uiState` that you are using in your Composable `val uiState: InterestsUiState = _uiState` is not a State and hence doesn't respond to changes. It's just a normal `InterestsUiState` initialized with the current value of `_uiState`.
To make it work, you can simply expose the getter for `_uiState`.

```kotlin
var uiState by mutableStateOf (InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    private set
```

Now this `uiState` can only be modified from inside the ViewModel and when you use this in your Composable, recomposition will happen whenever the value of `uiState` changes.